# Android - keeping the service alive even parent process is killed

Tags: android, android-service

I am new to Android. Right now I am just trying some examples which includes Services. In one of the example, service is created as a separate background process. Using something like this

```
android:process=":background"
```

They said now service will be having separate process environment and thus it is separate from the one(Application) that is started it. When I killed the parent process i.e.Application, the service is also getting killed. Is this normal behavior or not? Because what I understand from that article is Service wont get affected since it is different process environment. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks in advance

**UPDATE:**
Even I saw the same behavior if I use :remote.

Comment: IF user forcefully stop your application from setting , I think service too will killed..

Comment: @Ankit Thank you but what :remote & :background are intend to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just a copy from the Android document:

> If the name assigned to this attribute begins with a colon (':'), a
>   new process, private to the application, is created when it's needed.
>   If the process name begins with a lowercase character, a global
>   process of that name is created. A global process can be shared with
>   other applications, reducing resource usage

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/application-element.html#proc

Answer (score 1):

Afaik, there are two types of services,

1) background : which run in the same process of your application.

2) Remote :If we want to make this service run in a remote process (instead of the standard one for its .apk), we can use android:process in its manifest tag to specify one: ,

we can also use other strings  then background and remote.
here is service [lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#ServiceLifecycle)